# Change the position of the item that wraps to the next line

Tags: flutter

I'd like my button row (if and when it wraps) to align under item2. I've tried different align properties of `Wrap` but they involve changing the space between each item. IS there a way to change where the buttons wrap to on the next line without effecting the distance between the other items..

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) { 
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Welcome to Flutter'),
        ),
        body:  Wrap(
      direction: Axis.horizontal,
      crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.center,
          children:[
            Text('Item1'),
            SizedBox(width:40),
             Text('Item2'),
            SizedBox(width:40),
            Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children:[
                TextButton(child:Text("First Button"),onPressed:null),
                 SizedBox(width:40),
                
                TextButton(child:Text("First Button"),onPressed:null),
              ]
            )
            
          ]
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: this may be challenging: `CustomMultiChildLayout` - in return you are in full control where you place your children

Comment: any idea where to begin .. perhaps an example..?

Comment: sure: https://gist.github.com/pskink/0f82724b41d9ebe89604782fbf62fe03#file-multi_layout_painter-dart-L14 - it uses `CustomMultiChildLayoutPainter`, extended version of `CustomMultiChildLayout` but the whole idea with delegate is the same

Comment: basically you have to call `layoutChild` and `positionChild` on each child in the layout